# iOS: Accessibility: UICollectionView: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader Read out after cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, accessibility

I have a UICollection View, which has a Header view returned like this:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyView *myView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
        withReuseIdentifier:@"someIdentifier"
        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set various parameters on the view.
    return myView;
}
```

Then I have a bunch of Cells returned from cellForItemAtIndexPath obviously.

In Accessibility mode, when i 2 finger swipe up, it reads the Header View LAST, not First.   I need it to be read first.   I looked at the accessibilityPoint and accessibilityFrame, and both are correct.   The focused accessibility frame of the header is definitely above the cells.

So why would it be reading the header view last in accessibility mode?

Example: 
[image]

Comment: change the accessibility elements order.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems like an iOS bug to me, because obviously the Header should be read first by VoiceOver, before the Cells are read.

I have got around this issue by having section zero return only the header, and 0 rows.  Then having the next section (1) return NO header, and just rows.   Now VoiceOver reads everything in the correct order.  To the user, it looks the same, because they can't tell that the header is for a blank section without rows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the collection view's shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren property to true.

E.g.

```
self.collectionView.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true
```